# Contraction mapping of derivatives

Tags: derivatives, fixed-point-theorems, contraction-mapping

I have a complete metric space $(,||_{\infty})$ where $$ is a space of bounded and continuously differentiable function that is defined in $x∈[0,1]$
.

Suppose I have $v∈$ satisfying the following equation :

$$ v(x) = F(x) ⋅v(f())$$
for all $∈[0,1]$

One thing I know is that the mapping $T$ of $( v)(x) \equiv F(x) ⋅v(f())$ is a contraction mapping in the space.

What I'm interested in is to prove if the derivative of $v(x)$ also satisfies the contraction mapping. Assuming $F(x)$ is continuously differentiable, if I take the derivative on both sides :

$$v'(x) = F'(x)\cdot v(f(x)) + F(x) v'(f(x)) f'(x) $$

The way I'm trying to approach the problem is as follows :

1. Define $g(x) \equiv v'(x)$ and the fixed-point function of the original problem as $v^{*}(x)$. Then, the equation can be written by :

$$g(x) = F'(x) v^{*}(f(x)) + F(x) g(x)f'(x)$$

2. If I prove that the mapping $\widetilde{T}$ of $(\widetilde{T} g) \equiv  F'(x) v^{*}(f(x)) + F(x) g(x)f'(x)$ satisfies all the conditions of the contraction mapping theorem, then the fixed-point function $g^{*}(x)$ is $v'(x)$.

I wondered if this sounds plausible. One of my concerns is that if I can really plug in $v^{*}(x)$ in the first step. Should it be replaced by $\int g(x)dx$ so that it changes while doing iteration convergence?

Any comments or suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your notation. If $T$ is an operator on $S$, then would it not make more sense to write $(Tv)(x)$ instead of $(T\circ v)(x)$?  Regarding your concern, that depends on what you are trying to prove. Namely, how do you define $\tilde{T}$ for a given function in $S$?

Comment: I want a mapping that guarantees $g(x)$ to converge to $v^{*'}(x)$. The mapping without fixed $v^{*}(x)$, my concern was with the value of $v(0)$.

Comment: So the question is this: Is there a contraction mapping that has $v'(x)$ as its fixed point? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Hmm, not exactly. I was asking : given that it is a contraction mapping, is the fixed point function $v'(x)$?

Comment: Ok. I think I understand now.